# get_post_types() is returning null

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am trying to retrieve the post types and put them into an array with their slug being the index and their label being the value. When I `print_r( get_post_types() );` it returns the proper array with data, but when I try to use it like below, it returns null.

```
function get_posttype_list() {
        $pt_list = [];
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) );

        foreach( $post_types as $pt ) {
            $pt_list[ $pt->name ] = $pt->labels->singular_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `print_r( get_post_types( array( 'public' => true )));` does this return an array?

Comment: I see that you're filling up an array named `$pt_list` however nothing is done with this variable and there is no `return` statement, is your code incomplete? Can you update it with the rest of the function? How are you checking that it returns `null` and where is the code running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return your formatted array. Change the code like below

```php
function get_posttype_list() : array {
    $pt_list = [];
    $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );

    foreach( $post_types as $pt ) {
        $pt_list[ $pt->name ] = $pt->labels->singular_name;
    }
    return $pt_list;
}
```